# How to index polymorphic table in rails with not unique "association_type" and "association_id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic table called "Votes", where has votes from Answers and Questions.

Votes

```
user_id     voteable_id    voteable_type      value

   1             2            Answer            1
   2             2            Answer            1
```

In this case, the answer with id = 2 has two votes up.

The question is: **How to index this table?**

**First approach:**

```
add_index :votes, [:voteable_id, :voteable_type]
```

This will not work because duplicate key value will violates unique constraint

**Second approach:**

```
 add_index :votes, :voteable_id, 
 add_index :votes, :voteable_type
```

This one I guess will not have much performance because of the composite queries for id and type at the same time.

**Third approach:**

```
add_index :votes, [:user_id, :voteable_id, :voteable_type]
```

Is this last one a good one? Are three columns to be indexed too much?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

your first approach is the right one

```
add_index :votes, [:voteable_id, :voteable_type]
```

as long as you don't add `:unique => true` it will **not** be unique. And you shouldn’t make it unique, as this would result in only one vote per votable would be possible. As [Tashos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5909738/tashows) states in the comments.

The third approach would work too, and here you can use a `unique` constraint, so every user can only vote once per votable.

Comment: thanks! I dont know why it was generating with unique in my previous migrations. now it worked

Comment: Is there a difference between the first approach and second approach, or is it just a matter of syntax?

Comment: The first approach is an index on two fields, the second approach is two separate indices.

Comment: I know this is old, but wouldn't `add_index :votes, [:voteable_id, :voteable_type], :unique => true` forbid new votes on `Answer` with id = 2 be created? Once someone votes on Answer 2, noone else would be able to do the same. What you are actually looking for is the third migration, that will also make it impossible (since it's actually on the database level) for users to double vote an answer. Also if you query votes from a specific user, index helps there as well.

Comment: I read somewhere that the order of the fields listed in a compound index is important. will this index work on both queries?. Votes.where(_id: 'x', _type: 'x') and Votes.where(_type: 'x', _id: 'x')

Comment: I think the index `add_index :votes, [:voteable_type, :voteable_id]` makes more sense and efficient.